# Setting visible from false to true make program start again

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visible

I have two projects in **VB.NET** (win32 forms)

**1.** First application is for direct interaction with user. It has the option to activate my real-time engines from a checkbox.

**2.** Real-time engines (a form that runs in background when windows starts) but it also has checkboxes on it, so when I open it directly from p.#1, it should be visible. This form is imported by p#1.

So, I want that when project #2 is opened from a button from project #1, to be visible (because it has other options in it) and when it starts with windows, to be invisible. It's okay until now, but...

When project #2 is already running, If I will start it from project # 2 with the code above, it **will fire the load event** again and in taskmanager will run **two same processes**. I want just

when I run the code above to be **VISIBLE**,  **NOT** to run again in a new instance.

The code from p#2, that is called from p#1.

```
 Public Sub formsetup()

        If normalwindow = True Then
            Me.Size = New Size(466, 459)
            Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog
            Me.Opacity = 100
            Me.ShowInTaskbar = True
            Me.ShowIcon = True
            Me.ControlBox = True
            Me.Visible = True

        Else
            Me.Size = New Size(0, 0)
            Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
            Me.Opacity = 0
            Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
            Me.ShowIcon = False
            Me.ControlBox = False
            Me.Visible = False
            ' Panel1.Dispose()
            ' TextBox2.Dispose()

        End If
        Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub
```

It seems that the operation `me.visible = true` is the reason why load event from p#2 **fires again**.

I repeat, I want just **an instance** in memory of p#2, and when I click the button from p#1, p#2 to be just **visible**, **not** to load again in a new window.

*Thank you.*

Comment: you should show the part where the second app is accessed by the first.  if these truly are 2 different apps, that would clarify things.

Comment: The Public Sub is in App #2. I access it from App #1. For example, on Button1_click from app#1 to make application 2 visible (it is invisible by default) I write APP2.normalwindow = true APP2.formsetup()  . Now, it's the time when the Load event from APP#2 fires again and start in a new instance. The code Me.visible = true is the reason but why? And how could I make it visible without to start again? First application is a WPF form. Second one is Winform. I don't think that it should be such important, no?   Make single instance application checkbox is also enabled.

Comment: It's because the code me.visible = true is equivalent with the code form2.show() or form2.showdialog() ? That's the reason why my form from App2 start again? If yes, what else can I do ? I repeat, App2 starts with Windows and is invisible until I start it manually from App1 button1. Then it should be just Visible not to start a new instance of it. If I write in App1 the code  APP2.FORM2.VISIBLE = TRUE  is the same bug ... it starts again

Answer (score 0):

In your P#2 application properties check the 'Make Single Instance Application' check-box. 
[image]

Now since you are setting the form `Visible = False` when it gets activated again, it still remains invisible. To handle this we need to override `OnStartupNextInstance` under Application Events (Click View Application Events from Project Properties)

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStartupNextInstance(ByVal e As StartupNextInstanceEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnStartupNextInstance(e)
        MyBase.MainForm.Visible = True`
End Sub
```

Hope this is what you wanted.

**Edit:** Note that the mentioned event is raised in the first instance of the application itself, not the new one that's was trying to start, so there won't be any loaded event again.